# How to disable Windows File Protection in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

Is it possible to disable the Windows File Protection in Windows XP SP2 or above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to turn off Windows File Protection as been removed in SP2 (I guess that's why you are asking the question here). There is a registry tweak to get around this. It's explained in great detail here:
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Tweaking-XP-Windows-File-Protection-SP2.html